# Problems using malloc() to delete array within for loop

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have an array of data, `arr`, and an array of indexes, `index`. My goal is to use a for loop to create new arrays of data partitioned at each of the indexes and to further find the minimum in each partitioned array. I am using `malloc` to create a dynamic array which I then free at the end of each loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int j;
     int arr[] = {1,3,4,6,7,8,12,87,89,12,34,43,54,67,81,2,0,10,23,45,81,23,89,23,56,81,28,79};
     int index[] = {1,5,9,13,19,24};
     int h = 27;
     int k;
     int c;
     for(j = 0;j < h - 1;++j)
     {         
         int *temp_arr = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
         for(k = index[j];k<(index[j+1]);++k )
         {
             temp_arr[k] = arr[k];
         }
         int local_min ;
         local_min = temp_arr[0];
         for ( c = 1 ; c < sizeof(temp_arr) / sizeof(temp_arr[0]) ; c++ )
         {    printf("Temp array %d ", temp_arr[c]);
             if ( temp_arr[c] < local_min)
             {
                 local_min = temp_arr[c];
                 printf("Local min in loop %d ", local_min );
             }          
         }
         free(temp_arr);
         printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Unfortunately, the program is crashing without giving me any error messages. I think that I may have done something fundamentally wrong using `malloc`. Any suggestions on how to correctly do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are allocating `10` `int`s. What is this magical number? Apparently your indices are going above `10`.

Comment: My thinking here was that each of my temporary arrays will contain less than 10 ints?

Comment: What will be `temp_arr[k]` when `k = index[j]` and `j` is `5` ?

Comment: Does it matter what the spefic value is? My understanding was that me allocating 10 would mean the number of array elements?

Comment: `k = index[j]` : The first element is not included.

Comment: Can you answer this question? `k` will be `24`. `temp_arr[k]` will be *far* beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: OK. I think I understand now. I was thinking that when k was 24, my temp array would contain the elements from 24:27, or 3 elements

Comment: `temp_arr` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/JSmc3H)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ```
   for(j = 0;j < h - 1;++j) // Where h = 27
   ```

   It means `j` can be max `25`

   ```
   for(k = index[j];k<(index[j+1]);++k ) // If j = 25
   ```

   You are touching `index[26]`, while `index` has `6` elements.
2. ```
   for ( c = 1 ; c < sizeof(temp_arr) / sizeof(temp_arr[0]) ; c++ ) // Where int *temp_arr
   ```

   `temp_arr` is pointer and `sizeof(pointer)` is always `8` on 64bit or `4` on 32bit system.
3. ```
    for(k = index[j];k<(index[j+1]);++k )
    {
        temp_arr[k] = arr[k];              // Where int index[] = {1,5,9,13,19,24};
    }
   ```

   If `k` is `13` or `19` or `24` you are ouside of bounds.

---

You should take a look at [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), and debug your code, step by step, expression by expression.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you forgot to inspect the output from Valgrind, which shows exactly where you use uninitialized values and where you run off the end of `temp_arr`.

Note also that `temp_arr` is a pointer type, and `sizeof temp_arr` is the size of that pointer, not the size of the array it points to.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! I did not realise this about temp_arr